# IE8 Download's Writing to C:\?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, internet-explorer, download

Every time I download something using IE8 (running on Win 7) I get asked where to save the file, I choose my downloads folder, then the download continues and when complete I get the following message:

"C:\ is not accessible. Access Denied."

And I so I can't access any files I download. So why on earth would IE8 be trying to write to the root, and where can I change this? I've checked the cache folder location and it's correct.

**Update**: Discovered that this only happens with the 32 bit version of IE8. The 64bit version functions normally.

Dana

Comment: have you tried saving into a subfolder you create?

Comment: Yeah, tried that. Tried an external drive too. No luck. Ran Process Monitor and for some reason IE is doing queries against the root and failing. Why it's doing that I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

IE sucks for downloading files. IE will save the file to a temporary directory, then copy, yes, copy the file to the folder you want.

Do you have any security software running by any chance?

Comment: No security software running. What I don't get is why the 64bit version works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you save anything to the C:\ drive? I've had an issue before where I couldn't write anything to the C:\ because the drive had become "Read Only". If you can't then it's not an issue with IE but with the Windows installation. The only way I got round my issue was a complete reinstall unfortunately.